# Configure MongoDB with Django using pydev on Ubuntu and mac

Tags: django, mongodb, pydev

I want to setup mongoDb with Django using PyDev, I can use mongoDb and django both on terminal.
In the Database I have added the database engine to mongodb but then too when I try using syncDb Command in eclipse I am not able to sync instead gives some error.
Any help is appreciated.